# Ubuntu Classic does not work

Tags: 11.04, gnome

I don't know what I did that caused this, but when I log in to either Ubuntu Classic or Ubuntu Classic (No effects), the screen displays the wallpaper, but nothing else. The mouse still works and the screen isn't frozen or anything. The Terminal can still be accessed with Ctrl+Alt+T. Each time, I have had to logout from the Terminal and log on back into the regular Ubuntu with Unity, which still works.

***Update***

I logged back into Classic today and now there's the Unity interface instead of classic. Hmmmm...

Comment: So maybe your panels got deleted. Tried Adding new panels?

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. After logging into Classic, I opened the Terminal and typed `gnome-panel --replace` to try to reset the panels, but that did not do anything to the screen. The only difference is that the Terminal changes to show that something is running in it. I don't know if anyone has had this problem before, but I am troubled by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `metacity --replace` and `gnome-panel --replace`. The first one will reset everything. the second one will affect all panels you have enabled.

Comment: Thank you. `gnome-panel --replace` did nothing, but `metacity --replace` did the trick.